# make webpack DefinePlugin entry/chunk/file specific

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

In my webpack config, I'd like to be able to do the following:

```
module.exports = {
entry: {'main_public': [...], 'main_private': [...] },
...
plugins: [
   new CustomDefinePlugin({
      test: /_public$/,
      definitions: {PRIVATE_APP: false}
    }),
    new CustomDefinePlugin({
      test: /_private$/,
      definitions: {PRIVATE_APP: true}
    }),
   new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({compress: {dead_code: true}})
],
...}
```

That is I'd like to be able to do global definitions specific to different entry points.

I tried hacking around the existing `DefinePlugin` that comes with webpack, but it seems that it uses the `parser._plugins` system internally.  I also tried using setting a `test` field in the options I pass to the `UglifyJsPlugin` (and use `global_defs` there), but the `test` seemed to be ignored.

And ideas as to how I can easily make this work without forking the whole of webpack..although that is an option I suppose.

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution for that ?

Comment: I've been goolging this too; so far https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/5546#issuecomment-323581891 is the only workaround I could find